# What should be the query in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, group-by, where-clause, correlated-subquery

There is one table with coulmns :
id,bookid,name,dateofentry,status.

Need result where bookid and last dateofentry for corresponding book and status of book i.e R only 
(R- Return, and NR- Not return)

for e.g.
input :-

```
id bookid subject dateofentry Status
1   10      math   10-11-2012 NR
2   10      math   1-12-2012  R
3   110     math   1-12-2012  NR
4   110     math   10-12-2012 NR
5   102     math   10-11-2012 NR
6   102     math   1-12-2012  R
7   105     math   10-12-2012 NR
8   105     math   17-12-2012 NR
9   106     math   11-12-2012 NR
10  106     math   14-12-2012 R
```

output:-

```
10   math 1-12-2012 R
102  math 1-12-2012 R
106  math 14-12-2012 R
```

What should be the query for this

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:-

```
SELECT t.bookid, t.satus, r.MaxDate
FROM (SELECT bookid, MAX(dateofentry) as MaxDate
      FROM TempLogs
      GROUP BY bookid) r
INNER JOIN Logs t ON t.bookid = r.bookid AND t.dateofentry = r.MaxDate where status="R"
```

But I am getting some syntax error, and its not working.

Comment: wht syntax error your getting?

Comment: i dont remeber the exact lanugage but that is for subquery i have used.... no table exist,
if you could tell me the right answer based upon my question, that will be really great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the syntax error is because you're using 2 different table names. In your subquery, you are using table `TempLogs` but in the outer query, you refer to table `Logs`. Apart from that the actual query and methodology for what you're trying to achieve appears correct.

Comment: /******************
select t.bookid,t.status,r.MaxTime FROM (select Incident_Id,MAX(t.[End Date]) as MaxTime from Logs group by bookID) r 
inner join Logs t on t.bookid=r.bookId and t.[End Date]=r.MaxTime where t.[status]='R' 
********************************/
I Tried this, It executed fine, but gives me no result....
when I run this in Access 2007, I got two popups asking for values one for Incident_ID and second for t.End Date, the two attributes used in Subquery...
Please suggest

Comment: You can't bring out `Incident_Id` in the subquery but then group by the `BookId`, and also you refer to `[End Date]` in the `MAX()` column but it's only aliased as `t` in the outer query. I think you need something like `select t.bookid,t.status,r.MaxTime FROM (select bookid,MAX([End Date]) as MaxTime from Logs group by bookID) r inner join Logs t on t.bookid=r.bookId and t.[End Date]=r.MaxTime where t.[status]='R'`